# How do I optimize a table for selecting a SUM?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, query-optimization

Say I have a table with millions of records recording transactions on a bank account. (It isn't a bank account but close enough for the purposes of this question.)

- user (The ID of the user who owns this record.)
- amount (The integer amount added (+ve) or removed (-ve).)
- (Other fields)

I can run these SELECT commands to fetch the "balance" for any particular user or all users...

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS balance FROM MyTable where user = (id)
SELECT user, SUM(amount) AS balance FROM MyTable GROUP BY user
```

The trouble with this is that it takes longer the more records are added, and the table will grow.

I suspect (fear?) that the answer is to add a trigger which updates a second per-user table. I wonder, however, if this pattern is common enough for banking or accounting systems that DB systems have a built-in optimization designed for this very use?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would start with an index.  Be sure that you have an index on `(user, amount)`.  That will definitely help with the first query.

As for the second, it is going to be challenging.  This query needs to go through all the data, so your options for speeding it up is to use faster hardware.

In your case, your best option is to have a table with the current balances and to maintain this table using triggers.

Comment: I've never really tried this on 'lots of data', but how would an indexed view on the table (showing the SUM()ed data per user) perform versus home-grown triggers? In the triggers I can limit the processing to just the records in the `inserted` / `deleted` pseudo tables. Will the system be similarly smart enough to update only that part of the materialized view that is affected or will it "recalculate" the entire view whenever a single record is changed in the base table? (I probably should just test it out but I somehow think there is an 'it depends' coming up =)

Comment: @deroby . . . Your question is tagged mysql.  Why are you talking about features such as `inserted`/`deleted`/materialized views that are not part of MySQL?

Comment: My bad =( I was in the assumption I was browsing MSSQL tagged questions...

Answer (score 0):

Might it be better to have two tables -- one with all the transactions (as you have described) and one with balances at the end of each day.

A slightly different approach to this second table is to have the change for each day.  It would have `day`, `user`, and `change`.  A sum across this table would give you the current 'balance' faster.

I am assuming there are many 'transactions' per day per user.  If this is not the case, you might want to summarize by the week, or some other less frequent time period.

You would need to create and maintain this "Summary Table", since MySQL has no "materialized views".  [*Here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) is a discussion of efficiently using Summary tables for large Data Warehouse  applications.